Problems with prophet library for time series forecasting
I have a very small dataframe with two columns: time_key, which is a date and value which is a numerical variable meassuring the income of a supermarket. This dataframe defines a time series for which I have 16 months worth of data. I am trying to obtain predictions for the last 3 months.
I am using the fable and fable.prophet libraries in R. Eventhough this is a small example, the idea is that this process will be executed automatically to dozens of similar dataframes, so my idea is, for each dataframe, to automatically compute, optimize and compare different models and choose the one minimizing the accuracy. Here is a glance on my data:
sales.ts
time_key    value
1  2020-03-01 292.7846
2  2020-04-01 292.2414
3  2020-05-01 296.0398
4  2020-06-01 286.3656
5  2020-07-01 284.5536
6  2020-08-01 272.8100
7  2020-09-01 272.8052
8  2020-10-01 326.2926
9  2020-11-01 306.6977
10 2020-12-01 370.4489
11 2021-01-01 323.3679
12 2021-02-01 308.2357
13 2021-03-01 346.5880
14 2021-04-01 331.0101
15 2021-05-01 303.5761
16 2021-06-01 204.9440

The following script builds ARIMA, ETS and prophet models on the data and compares them:
library(tidyverse)
library(tsibble)
library(fable)
library(prophet)
library(fable.prophet)

fit <- sales.ts %>%
  mutate(time_key = yearmonth(time_key)) %>% 
  as_tsibble(index = time_key) %>%
  model(
    ets = ETS(value),
    arima = ARIMA(value),
    prophet = prophet(value))

fc <- fit %>% forecast(h = 3)

fc %>% autoplot(sales.ts)

You can see here the results.

As you can see none seem very promising. My questions are:

What on earth is happening with prophet? Specially because if I call the fit %>% accuracy() command, prophet shows an error of 0.
Do you have any suggestions on how to improve this?

I know that there may be much room to optimize the models indicating patterns like trend and seasonality (although this specific data does not show much of any) but I need this proces to be automatic so I cannot go dataset by dataset finetuning the model.

Would you be willing to edit your post to work in base R instead of the tidyverse (which IMO adds an unnecessary hurdle in the form of less legible code)? And while you are at it, ideally make your data immediately consumable by use through the dput() command?

The prophet model was designed for daily data, and while it can be made to work for other frequencies, the default settings require modification. You will have received a warning about the number of changepoints used, which should have been a hint that something was wrong. In this case it is completely overfitting (so the insample fit is perfect). Here is an example where the settings are more appropriate for your data set.
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(tsibble)
library(fable)
library(fable.prophet)

sales.ts <- tribble(
  ~time_key, ~value,
  "2020-03-01", 292.7846,
  "2020-04-01", 292.2414,
  "2020-05-01", 296.0398,
  "2020-06-01", 286.3656,
  "2020-07-01", 284.5536,
  "2020-08-01", 272.8100,
  "2020-09-01", 272.8052,
  "2020-10-01", 326.2926,
  "2020-11-01", 306.6977,
  "2020-12-01", 370.4489,
  "2021-01-01", 323.3679,
  "2021-02-01", 308.2357,
  "2021-03-01", 346.5880,
  "2021-04-01", 331.0101,
  "2021-05-01", 303.5761,
  "2021-06-01", 204.9440
) |>
  mutate(time_key = yearmonth(time_key)) |>
  as_tsibble(index = time_key)

fit <- sales.ts |>
  model(
    ets = ETS(value),
    arima = ARIMA(value),
    prophet = prophet(value ~ growth(n_changepoints = 1) +
                    season(period = 12, order = 2, type = "additive"))
  )

fc <- fit |> forecast(h = 3)

fc |> autoplot(sales.ts, level = NULL)


Created on 2024-06-20 with reprex v2.1.0
